# Why would you deliver a video in 1920x964?

Tags: video, aspect

Quite simply; I've never come across this aspect ratio in video before and I just wanted to know if there is a standard in video (that I'm unaware of) that routinely uses this aspect ratio.

For a little extra background: an outsourced company in the States produced a video for us (we're based in the UK) and they delivered the video in 1920x964 and I really don't want to go back to them and ask 'why?' in case I seem like an idiot, so I'm checking with you gals and guys first :D

I know I've never heard of that ratio but I didn't know if it were more standard either in the US or in a different branch of film-making that I'm not party to.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a good reason why 1920x964.  It is not uncommon to see 2:1 aspect ratios, which would be 1920x960.  The extra 4 pixels are a mystery, especially because 960 divides by 8 and 16, which make it very JPG friendly.  964 does not divide evenly by 8, either.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes up against something similar, I think I've found an answer: websites or, more specifically, web browsers.

I've spoken to our front-end developer and he's informed me that it's incredibly likely that this aspect ratio was chosen so that the film could be displayed at full resolution on a website (taking into account the address-bar at the top of the browser window and any footer (like the Windows taskbar, for example) at the bottom. The ~120 pixel difference means that the video will appear to be 'full-screen' with the header and footer of the browser/OS visible.

I still think it's weird because playing this in actual full-screen on a monitor/TV will result in letterboxing but... whatever.